# How to push laravel packages and helper files through git

Tags: php, laravel, package

If I don't have ssh access and can't run composer command over server.

How can I upload laravel packages properly through GIT repository, so that my project will run without any problem .

I know If I remove vendor folder from root .gitignore then vendor file will up to the server.

But still I have doubt, I have to do other thinks also.

I am not good in git thats why before messing laravel I am asking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recommendation is not to commit the `vendor` directory, that's why Laravel ships with a `.gitignore` file that contains the `vendor` directory amongst other things.

However, there are situations such as yours where this is not possible, so in that case there is a nice section of the [Composer Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/) that offers some advice on how you should handle committing the dependencies to version control:

> [Should I commit the dependencies in my vendor directory?](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)