# Why is vendor package not pushing to github even when "/vendor" is not listed in .gitignore file?

Tags: laravel, github, gitignore, git-add

When I add files to my local repository, some vendor packages are excluded even though they are not listed in the .gitignore file.  Since they are not pushed to the remote repository, other developers are not able to pull the vendor packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push laravel packages and helper files through git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967266/how-to-push-laravel-packages-and-helper-files-through-git)

Answer (score 0):

The Vendors files are not to upload on github.The composer.json file of your laravel project have all the information to install all of your vendors.So try to update your composer.
To update composer use cmd or terminal command:

```
composer update
composer install
```

Be sure that the composer.json file is not ignore by .gitignore file.

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the root .gitignore is not enough.

I had the same problem and found out that there are multiple .gitignore in subfolders.

[image]